# Probabilistic Polynomial Time Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Let $C$ be a language and $M$ be a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm where $w \notin C$ implies $\mathbb{P}\{M\; accepts\; w\} \leqslant 1/8$, and  $w \in C$ implies $\mathbb{P}\{M\; accepts\; w\} \geqslant 1/4$.

How do I go about proving that there is another probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $M'$ that on input $x \in C$, accepts with probability $\geqslant 9/16$ and if $x \notin C$ then it accepts with probability $\leqslant 7/16$.

Then, also prove $M''$ with accepts $\geqslant 2/3$ when $x \in C$, and if not accepts with probability $\leqslant 1/3$

Not really sure how to approach the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "probabilistic" qualifier means that the algorithm returns results that satisfy the probability inequalities independently on successive runs, then let $M'(w)$ be the algorithm that checks $M(w)$ three times and accepts if any run of $M$ would have accepted.

Then $M'$ satisfies the condition and determines membership in $C$ correctly with probability $>1/2$. So we can get an algorithm that determines membership in $C$ correctly with any desired probability $<1$ by repeating $M'$ a finite number of times.